# How to avoid the view sliding down after setStatusBarHidde:NO

Tags: objective-c, ios, hidden, statusbar, overlap

The question is simple: how I can avoid the view sliding down when I call:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

The result I want to obtain is, in practice, that the status bar overlaps my view.
Thanks.

L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is:

```
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could set the y position of your view to -20 to have this effect. Or maybe just do this:

```
 self.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
```

Comment: I didn't get anything.. Because of the wantsFullScreenLayout were set to NO, the view automatically resized when the statusBar were shown. As my self-answer says, it fixed the problem :)